# Getting protein sequences by accessing Uniprot (with Python)

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a list of protein id's I'm trying to access the protein sequences from Uniprot with python.
I came across this post :[Protein sequence from uniprot protein id python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569622/protein-sequence-from-uniprot-protein-id-python) but gives a list of elements and not the actual sequence:

### Code

```
import requests as r
from Bio import SeqIO
from io import StringIO

cID='P04637'

baseUrl="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"
currentUrl=baseUrl+cID+".fasta"
response = r.post(currentUrl)
cData=''.join(response.text)

Seq=StringIO(cData)
pSeq=list(SeqIO.parse(Seq,'fasta'))
```

which gives output:

### output

```
[SeqRecord(seq=Seq('MQAALIGLNFPLQRRFLSGVLTTTSSAKRCYSGDTGKPYDCTSAEHKKELEECY...SSS', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='sp|O45228|PROD_CAEEL', name='sp|O45228|PROD_CAEEL', description='sp|O45228|PROD_CAEEL Proline dehydrogenase 1, mitochondrial OS=Caenorhabditis elegans OX=6239 GN=prdh-1 PE=2 SV=2', dbxrefs=[])]
```

I was just curious on how I can actually get the sequence itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[record.seq for record in pSeq]`

edit:
You'll want `str(pSeq[0].seq)`

Comment: This only gives partial sequence, stores the elements as a list.

Comment: @bioinformatics_student, check the elements in your list again

Comment: I get a lot of elements out of range for certain proteins, probably because some elements are returned as empty items.

Comment: you can wrap it with error handling (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) or write an `if len(pSeq) > 1:` that checks if the query returned empty or not